# Proxy cannot be removed

Tags: terminal, network, proxy

I tried to remove the configured proxy on my machine via the System Preferences, but after unchecking all proxies in the settings, it still uses the proxy.

[image]

And if I check the proxy via `scutil --proxy` I still see the active profile:

[image]

So my question: is it possible to disable this proxy-script via the terminal?

Comment: Have you reboot your computer after uncheck proxy?

Comment: yes of course..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. That setting could come from a VPN app (like Cisco AnyConnect). Do you have such an app installed on your Mac?